# How to query child to parent

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, sosl

How to query child to parent like contact to parent..and how to query master lookup relations.

```
select id,lastnam,(select id,name from account where accountid=conatctid)from contact
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just an example on how the parent-child query works...

**Ways of writing Parent - Child Queries for Standard Objects**

```
Select Id, Name, (Select Id, LastName from Contacts where Lastname='Frank') from Account

Select Id, LastName, Account.Name from Contact
```

**Ways of writing Parent - Child Queries for Custom Objects**

```
Select Id, Name, (Select Id, Name from Custom_Object2s__r) from Custom_Object1__c

Select Id, Name, Custom_Object1__r.Name from Custom_Object2__c
```

Hope this might helps...

Comment: are you trying to query Account in subquery? without from ?

Comment: This query is not working fine

Comment: @Hemalatha paruchuri, That's k, I didn't understand your question either... hope you find your solution

Comment: your first query should be  `Select Id, LastName, (Select id, LastName from Contacts where LastName='ContactName' ) from Account`  your where and from place need to be change

Answer (score 8):

If you want get the parent object information then you need to use like this.

### SOQL Child to Parent

```
for(Contact objContact: [SELECT Id, LastName, AccountId, Account.Name FROM Contact])
{
  system.debug('====Account Name======'+objContact.Account.Name);
}
```

if you want any other info about Account then you need to use Account.FieldAPIName... this way you will be able to get the Account info

### SOQL Parent to child

```
for(Account objAccount: [SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, LastName FROM Contacts)  FROM Account])
{
    for(Contact objContact: objAccount.Contacts)
    {
       system.debug('====Contact onfo======'+objContact);
    }
 }
```

Comment: this is the only way to query child to parent in soql

Comment: @Hemalathaparuchuri yes this is the only way to query from child to parent.

Comment: ok ratan ..in parent child to parent query [select id.name,{select id,lastname from contacts) from account];       is there any way to query child to parent query

Comment: @Hemalathaparuchuri no. you can't query like that. I have added both child to parent and parent to child structure in my answer. this is the only way you could use the relationship query.  is there anything you are trying to figure it out that i am not aware ?

Comment: @Hemalathaparuchuri great.

Comment: @Hemalathaparuchuri if your issue resolved then pls accept the answer which is most useful Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can traverse a relationship from a child object (`contact`) to a field on its parent (`Account.Name`) by using dot notation.

You can traverse multiple levels upwards!

```
List<Contact> list= [Select ID,LastName,Account.Name, Account.Industry from Contact where Name='abcd'];
   for(Contact c: list){
      System.debug('Contact LastName is:' + c.LastName);
      System.debug('Account Name is:' + c.Account.Name);
   }
```

Comment: .in parent child to parent query [select id.name,{select id,lastname from contacts) from account]; is there any way to query child to parent query.and one more thing how to query lookup relations

Comment: @Hemalathaparuchuri This the format only.

Comment: From Parent to child-> Inner Query is used  and from child to parent we have to use Dot notation. like above format.

Comment: Welcome @Hemalathaparuchuri . I am glad that, your doubt is clear. Happylearning:)

Answer (score -2):

we can understand it by an example. We have Account and Contact Object and we know that the relationship between them is lookup relationship.
Note : This relationship has one property called cascadedelete that is why, when you will delete a contact, it's parent will got deleted.

Child To Parent SOQL ;
[ SELECT Name,Phone,Email,AccountId,Account.Name,Account.Phone,Account.BillingAddress FROM Contact ]

Comment: Please use code quotes for better readability.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Your contributions on SFSE is welcome, however, this 6-year-old question was answered sufficiently three times 6 years ago. While it is acceptable in general to add new answers to old questions, your answer does not add much extra - except the mention of cascade delete, which the question does not ask about & which you do not explain very clearly. I am assuming these are some of the reasons that your answer has been downvoted. I suggest that you consider deleting this answer, and instead find some unanswered questions that you can help with.